# Looping over a query output using a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, unix

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u root -password << EOF
use runk_prd;
SELECT user_push_token FROM users WHERE user_push_token <> 'NULL' | while read guid user_push_token; do
    echo "pushToken: $user_push_token"
EOF
```

I'm trying to run the script above but instead of returning a list of push tokens it's giving me the following error:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'while read guid user_push_token' at line 1
```

I've tested the query in the MySQL web app and there it worked fine.

Comment: I think the issue is obvious if you understand the meaning of the syntaxes you're using; the `| while read ...` part was clearly intended to be processed by Bash, but instead it's being passed as input to MySQL. Are you trying to cobble together code-snippets without understanding them?

Answer (score 0):

You missplaced the pipe symbol:

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u root -password << EOF |
use runk_prd;
SELECT user_push_token FROM users WHERE user_push_token <> 'NULL'
EOF
while read user_push_token; do
    echo "pushToken: $user_push_token"
done
```